# Package Analysis in Docker Image

Tags: docker, security, package, dockerfile, clair

I have pulled a few images to my base machine, and need to analyze the package-versions/installed-libraries version that is currently present in that image.

Is there any command/tool to do that?

Comment: I know that Clair does the same job, however, that is an automated way to do so. I want to understand how it fuzzes the image to get the package info and I want to analyze the package version manually or the list of package present.